# How to handle static analysis warning from Core Guidelines checker about gsl::at?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, static-analysis, cpp-core-guidelines

I activated static analysis for my project in Visual Studio. The Core Guidelines checker says i should use gsl::at for subscription. But my code is save. What's the cleanest way to get rid of this warning? Should I disable it? Should I write my code differently? Should I use gsl::at introducing an overhead for the check? My code is:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void increase(T(&data)[N])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        data[i] +=1;
}
```

Comment: Added a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: In your example you could use range-for. There is no need for indexing.

Comment: I no longer use an index based iteration. I did some tests with the Visual Studio compiler and realized that using index_sequence and variadic templates instead of a loop produces faster code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. Because the size is known at compile time, it is possible to use a std::array, std::get and std::index_sequence. std::get leads to a compilation error if the index is out of bounds. There is no longer a need for a runtime check.

```
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr void noop(Ts...) noexcept {}

template <typename T, size_t N, size_t... I>
constexpr void increase(std::array<T, N>& data, std::index_sequence<I...>) noexcept
{
    noop((std::get<I>(data) += 1)...);
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr void increase(std::array<T, N>& data) noexcept
{
    increase(data, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```